# Read multiple colons from Access database and put each of them to array with VBScript

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I have a database containing one table with several colons. Table information will be used in calculations. 
For example, in table with 3 colons "Type", "Length", "Width" I have next data:

1. (1. Square 2. Its Length 3. Its Width)
2. (1. Triangle 2. Its Length 3. Its Width)

I need to calculate areas for every figure - obviously, I will have to use different formulas for them. Information about each figure stored in corresponding row.

Here is the example code I use to access database:

```
Option Explicit
Dim databaseConnection, strConnect
Set databaseConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\example.mdb"

databaseConnection.Open strConnect

Dim type, typeArray
Dim length, lengthArray
Dim width, widthArray
Dim connectionA, connectionB, connectionC

Function findValues(valueString, valueArray, connection)

Do While Not connection.EOF
    valueString = valueString + connection.Fields(0) & ","
    connection.MoveNext
Loop
valueArray = Split(valueString, ",")
End Function

Set connectionA = databaseConnection.execute("SELECT Type FROM ExampleTable")
Call findValues(type, typeArray, connectionA)
Set connectionB = databaseConnection.execute("SELECT Length FROM ExampleTable")
Call findValues(length, lengthArray, connectionB)
Set connectionC = databaseConnection.execute("SELECT Width FROM ExampleTable")
Call findValues(width, widthArray, connectionC)
```

For now, let's not bother with calculations, and just find out if our code is correct:

```
WScript.echo(typeArray(1) & & lengthArray(1) & widthArray(1))

Set databaseConnection = Nothing

WScript.sleep 60000
```

It outputs figure type, but not it's length or width. So, neither length nor width can be used in calculating. Any clues, why is it so? Maybe suggestions how to simplify my decision?

Kindly yours, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It outputs figure type, but not it's length or width.

That's because you only read `fields(0)` and forget `fields(1)` and `Fields(2)`:

```
Do While Not connection.EOF
    valueString = valueString + connection.Fields(0) & ","
    connection.MoveNext
Loop
```